# Undefined offset error and undefined variable error even if defined

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that I am writing to take in values datetime values from an array and convert it into hours and minutes format like 0010. I want to use this to later extract other values from the array as this is an associative array

```
function getData($lengthArray, $csvdat) {  # passing down the values of the array and the length of the array
                 $newData = array(  
                            'nightTime1',
                            'nightTime2',
                            'dayTime1',
                            'peakTime',
                            'dayTime2',
                            'winterNightTime1',
                            'winterNightTime2',
                            'winterDayTime1',
                            'winterDayTime2',
                            'winterPeakTime');

                for ($count = 0; $count <= $lengthArray; $count++ ) {  #looping to the length of the array

                        $arrayTimestamp = $csvdat[$count]['timestamp']; 
                        $comparator = date('Hs', strtotime($arrayTimestamp)); #extracting the time format            
                        $nightTime1 = 0759;
                        $dayTime1 =   1659; 
                        $peakTime = 1859;   
                        $dayTime2 = 2259;   
                        $nightTime2 = 2359;

                        if ( $comparator ==  $nightTime1 ) {
                                if (empty($newData['nightTime1'])) {
                                        $newData['nightTime1'] = $nightTime;
                                        $newData['nightTime1']['phase1'] = $csvdat[$count++]['day_chan1'];
                                        $newData['nightTime1']['phase1'] = $csvdat[$count++]['day_chan2'];
                                        $newData['nightTime1']['phase1'] = $csvdat[$count++]['day_chan3'];                                          
                                }
                                else if (!empty($newData)) {

                                }

                        }

                }

                return $newData;


          }
            getData($lengthData , $csvdata);

            var_dump($newData);
```

The problem I am facing now is that I get an Undefined offset error at the line

```
$arrayTimestamp = $csvdat[$count]['timestamp'];
```

and an undefined variable for `$newData`. I am not very good at php so please advise.

Here is the `var_dump` of the `csvdat` array

```
  array (size=118061)
  0 => 
    array (size=15)
      'timestamp' => string '01/02/2014 00:00' (length=16)
      'curr_property' => string '5972' (length=4)
      'curr_property_cost' => string '62' (length=2)
      'day_property' => string '19' (length=2)
      'day_property_cost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_solar_generating' => string '2898' (length=4)
      'curr_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'day_solar_generated' => string '9' (length=1)
      'day_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_chan1' => string '2189' (length=4)
      'curr_chan2' => string '2898' (length=4)
      'curr_chan3' => string '885' (length=3)
      'day_chan1' => string '7' (length=1)
      'day_chan2' => string '9' (length=1)
      'day_chan3' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=15)
      'timestamp' => string '01/02/2014 00:00' (length=16)
      'curr_property' => string '5215' (length=4)
      'curr_property_cost' => string '54' (length=2)
      'day_property' => string '37' (length=2)
      'day_property_cost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_solar_generating' => string '2141' (length=4)
      'curr_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'day_solar_generated' => string '16' (length=2)
      'day_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_chan1' => string '2173' (length=4)
      'curr_chan2' => string '2141' (length=4)
      'curr_chan3' => string '901' (length=3)
      'day_chan1' => string '14' (length=2)
      'day_chan2' => string '16' (length=2)
      'day_chan3' => string '5' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=15)
      'timestamp' => string '01/02/2014 00:00' (length=16)
      'curr_property' => string '5215' (length=4)
      'curr_property_cost' => string '54' (length=2)
      'day_property' => string '54' (length=2)
      'day_property_cost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_solar_generating' => string '2157' (length=4)
      'curr_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'day_solar_generated' => string '23' (length=2)
      'day_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_chan1' => string '2157' (length=4)
      'curr_chan2' => string '2157' (length=4)
      'curr_chan3' => string '901' (length=3)
      'day_chan1' => string '21' (length=2)
      'day_chan2' => string '23' (length=2)
      'day_chan3' => string '8' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=15)
      'timestamp' => string '01/02/2014 00:00' (length=16)
      'curr_property' => string '5183' (length=4)
      'curr_property_cost' => string '54' (length=2)
      'day_property' => string '71' (length=2)
      'day_property_cost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_solar_generating' => string '2125' (length=4)
      'curr_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'day_solar_generated' => string '31' (length=2)
      'day_solar_export' => string '0' (length=1)
      'curr_chan1' => string '2173' (length=4)
      'curr_chan2' => string '2125' (length=4)
      'curr_chan3' => string '885' (length=3)
      'day_chan1' => string '28' (length=2)
      'day_chan2' => string '31' (length=2)
      'day_chan3' => string '11' (length=2)
```

Comment: Would you please show us the content of `$csvdat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** and only if you are 100% sure that `$lengthArray` is the size of the `$csvdat` array, then your error is caused by this line:

```
for ($count = 0; $count <= $lengthArray; $count++ ) {
```

it should be

```
for ($count = 0; $count < $lengthArray; $count++ ) {
```

Right now you're breaking the loop if the `$count` is lower OR the same as `$lengthArray`. Notice that last key in your array is `3` and its length is `4`.

---

### EDIT

Now about *Undefined variable: $newData*.

You're trying to `var_dump($newData)` which is undefined. It exists inside the `getData` function but not outside it. Maybe you wanted to do it like this:

```
$newData = getData($lengthData , $csvdata);
var_dump($newData);
```

Comment: thanks that did solve the problem for the offset. However the error still exists for undefined variable $newData

Comment: I found my mistake. Thanks, it was not what you pointed out though

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for ($count = 0; $count < $lengthArray; $count++ )
```

instead of

```
for ($count = 0; $count <= $lengthArray; $count++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **$count < $lengthArray** in for loop

```
for ($count = 0; $count < $lengthArray; $count++ ) {
}
```